# Bind events on dynamic generated php buttons

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a simple table that manages a list of user created posts. Inside the table, I have two buttons that are supposed to manage the edit or the deletion of the single posts.

I have a problem with these buttons, when I try to edit one entry that isn't the first one listed, no actions occur. How i can manage this? I know that every button need an unique id, but i can't figure out how to fix this because the buttons are dynamically generated with a php `for()` loop.

```
<tbody>
    <? for($n=0;$n<count($load);$n++): ?>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row"><? echo $n; ?></th>
        <td class="postListTitle"><? echo $load[$n]['post_title']; ?></td>
        <td id="postListDate"><? echo $load[$n]['post_date']; ?></td>
        <td class="button-group"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-edit-post">Edit</button><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btn-delete-post">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    <? endfor; ?>
</tbody>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('#btn-edit-post').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var postTitle = $('.postListTitle').html();

    $.ajax({
        url:'system/ajax/doPost.php?title='+encodeURIComponent(postTitle),
        type:'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(item){
            var post = JSON.parse(item);

            $('#edit-title').attr('value',post.title);
            $('#edit-text').append(post.text);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: From the behaviour you describe it sounds like you're selecting the elements by `id` attribute, but the issue there is that you're creating multiple elements with the same `btn-edit-post` id - which is invalid. Change that to a `class` instead. Also note that it would be helpful for us to see your JS/jQuery code too

Comment: @uncleB use `class` rather than `id`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for the tip. The jquery code is working fine, my issue is only related on how to manage these buttons. Anyway i will post the jquery code to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to understand is that all your button have the same ID which is `btn-edit-post` and `btn-delete-post` an ID attribute must be unique, therefore you need to create the ID's dynamically.Like this

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="edit_<?=$load[$n]['post_id']?>">Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="delete_<?=$load[$n]['post_id']?>">Delete</button></td>
```

See the ID is dynamically for the edit make the id edit_(PoSTID) for the delete make it delete_(POSTID)

Then on your jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('[id^="edit_"]').on('click',function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]; //get the post ID

            //continue what you need.

        });
        </script>
```

delete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('[id^="delete_"]').on('click',function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]; //get the post ID

            //continue what you need.

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Using the class instead of the id as suggested is working fine, but now the issue is related to the post title. I will try to fix it by assigning the post id to the title and to the edit and delete buttons

Comment: better use ID rather than a class, but make sure the ID is created dynamically

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will assign the actual id plus the $n generated from the php `for()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the selector to a static element.

```
$(document).on('click','#btn-edit-post', function(e){
    ...
});
```

Also I agree with the comment, if you have multiple rows that have the buttons share with the same id, you better switch to use class instead.

Comment: I will try also this solution. Do you think it's better to use the class workaround also on the post title to get it using the `.html()` jquery function?

Comment: If you only have 1 item on the page, it's ok to use either id or class. If you have multiple items, then class should be desired. As id supposed to be unique per item.

Comment: Ok, perfect. But I've already assigned a class to the post title, unfortunately, it select only the first title of the list.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's going on. The class selector should select all the items with the same class, and you should be able to access them with index, e.g. $('.postListTitle')[1]. If it's still unclear, can you create a jsfiddle so I can see what's the problem is.

Comment: Here is the js fiddle of the actual code https://jsfiddle.net/b1761wsa/ .I'm working to add the `$n` generated with the `for()` php loop to the id, then fetch it using jquery.

Comment: I see you have added this line to the code to get the post title `$(this).closest('tr').find('.postListTitle').html();` . My workaround to achieve this was this `$('.postListTitle').attr('id').val()` but i will try also your solution. Thank you

Comment: Yep. Because you may have multiple items with postListTitle class, This is to make sure, after you clicked the edit button, you got the text from the same row of the button.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Do you think also my workaround will work? `var postTitleId = $('.postListTitle').attr('id',function(){$(this).closest('tr').val();console.log(this);});`

Comment: $('.postListTitle').attr('id') will give you the id of the of the first .postListTitle item, which always gonna be the first row. Also since the id is a string, there is no .val() method on string, so there will be an error on that.

Comment: I was testing this solution, the console show me the two items id's of the posts, but no error was logged. Anyway i will use the `.colosest()` and `.find()` as you suggested.